# show 1 data instead of all ngFor - Angular 11

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular-ui, angular11, angular-template

Im trying to display total counts of enrollment with `item.male_students` & `item.female_students`

**UPDATE** 
remove the ngFor now it works as expected.
here's my component.html

```
<thead class="thead-zircon">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Total Enrollment Quick Count
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody class="list">
    <tr>
        <td>
            {{ maleCount + femaleCount }}
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

**UPDATED** 
here's my component.ts

```
data: []; 

  constructor(private apiService: ApiService) {
    super();
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getEnrollMentCountBySex();
  }

  getEnrollMentCountBySex() {
    this.apiService.getAll('enrollments', "/count-student-enrollment-by-sex-and-academic-level")
    .subscribe(data => {
      this.data = data;
      this.maleCount = data.reduce(((acc, item) => acc + item.male_students), 0);
      this.femaleCount = data.reduce(((acc, item) => acc + item.female_students), 0);
    });
  }
```

Im getting object. Here's and image from api endpoint

[image]

**UPDATE** 
But im getting all the index. I only want the total count of male & female students to be shown in table

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as soon as you receive data from ajax. That's the good way I would suggest you in this case.

```
getEnrollMentCountBySex() {
   this.apiService.getAll('enrollments', "/count-student-enrollment-by-sex-and-academic-level").subscribe(data => {
      this.data = data;
      this.maleCount = data.reduce((acc, item) => acc + item.male_students), 0);
      this.femaleCount = data.reduce((acc, item) => acc + item.female_students), 0);
   });
}
```

HTML

```
Male Count - {{ maleCount }}
Female Count - {{ femaleCount }}
```

---

If `data` is being modified from `user` in your case and we wanted to keep UI bindings updated. Then definitely using `Pipe` or `function` call on binding would be a better idea.

```
@Pipe({name: 'countByProp'})
export class CountByPropPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(data: any, prop: string): number {
    if (!prop) throw new Error('Please pass property name');
    return data.reduce((acc, item) => acc + item[prop]), 0);
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
Male Count - {{ data | countByProp: 'male_students' }}
Female Count - {{ data | countByProp: 'female_students' }}
```

**TS**

Define `maleCount` and `femaleCount` variable in your `HomePage.ts`

```
maleCount = 0;
femaleCount = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer bro. Tried the code im getting some formatting error in vscode.

Comment: @Kael can you please share, what exactly it is?

Comment: Sorry for taking to long to get back to you bro. I have updated the post.

Comment: @Kael check updated answer last section, you have to declare the varaible in your `home.page.ts` file

Comment: I see thanks for the efforts bro. I'll try it and test it.

Comment: Hello bro tested it. Im getting 2 in every index now still getting all index.

Comment: @Kael sorry I don't get you, can you please elaborate?

Comment: Hello it seems i've just misunderstand your answer. it now works bro thanks.

Comment: Already did bro. Awesome minimal code bdw bro.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a slightly different approach. (though I would also prefer using pipes). Here we use `| async` pipe which takes care of unsubscribe and using `tap` we create a sideeffect and calculate totals of from the `data`.

```html
<tbody class="list">
    <tr *ngFor="let item of data$ | async; let i = index">
        <td>
            {{ item.male_students + item.female_students }}
        </td>
    </tr>
    total males: {{totalMaleStudents}}
   total females: {{totalFemaleStudents}}
</tbody>
```

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  data$: any;
  totalFemaleStudents = 0;
  totalMaleStudents = 0;

  ngOnInit() {
    const apiData = [
      { name: 'elementary', id: 1, female_students: 1, male_students: 1 },
      { name: 'highschool', id: 2, female_students: 0, male_students: 0 },
      { name: 'junior', id: 3, female_students: 0, male_students: 0 },
    ];

    // mock
    this.data$ = of(apiData).pipe(
      tap((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        
        // validate
        if (!Array.isArray(data)) {
          return;
        }

        // calculate
        for (let i = 0; i < data.length - 1; i++) {
          if (data[i]?.female_students) {
            this.totalFemaleStudents += data[i]?.female_students;
          }
          if (data[i]?.male_students) {
            this.totalMaleStudents += data[i]?.male_students;
          }
        }
      })
    );
  }
}
```

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nvw55f?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Thank you for taking the time bro to create a different approach. It's nice to see. It can be done it multiple ways.